# How to straightforwardly implement selective A/B testing in a React Native app?

Tags: react-native

I have a React Native app with several thousand users. I want to make small changes to the app, but in a way that will touch a lot of files. I want a specified list of users to see the new changes. At the top-level, I know how I could determine which group the user is in, but can I make my changes without doing an (unrealistic, messy) amount of if statements?

I can only think of:

- Introducing lots of if statements
- Copying components and serving them for users in B
- Somehow generating 2 bundles and serving one for A and one for B (however I can't see how this could be done with version control. Ideally I would like to essentially switch branch for a B user)

It really seems like a problem that should have a very simple solution, so please let me know if I'm just missing something.

Comment: The simple solution is generally to use any of the numerous frameworks which exist for this (LaunchDarkly etc - not a recommendation, probably the most well known one). Why did you rule those out?

Comment: Didn't know they existed, thank you!